# Apache doesn't restart after configuring Zend Guard - CentOS 7

Tags: linux, apache, centos7, zend-guard

i downloaded and installed the Zend Guard library on my Centos7 server and after put the config lines into the php.ini file and restart apache... apache doesn't want to restart..

Here is my php version :

```
[root@XXXXXXXXXX home]# php -v
PHP 5.5.29 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2015 10:49:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.18, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
```

I installed Zend Guard Loader for PHP 5.5 - 64 bit like that :

- i put the 2 files (`ZendGuardLoader.so` and `opcache.so`) into `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`
- i added these lines at the bottom of my php.ini file :

  `zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so`
  `zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so`
  zend_loader.enable=1

and i restarted apache and nothing, must hit ctrl-c , comment the lines and restart.

I tried just with `ZendGuardLoader.so` and it was the same result.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What about /var/log/apache2 log files? Is there some error messages?

Comment: Apache is refusing to run because there's a lot of things that may have gone wrong.

Comment: @alvits apache start if i remove the lines about zendguard... it doesn't work only if i had this 2 lines

Comment: Most likely it is complaining and writing in log file that it cannot load the module. Get rid of it then.

Answer (score 0):

please execute the command

## httpd -t

to see the error

It will show you the row number where the wrong confguration exist

regards

Comment: Hi, i tried it last day and there's no syntax error...

httpd -t
Syntax OK

like if the error was only in the library... but i didn't have any information :/

Comment: Hi, did you try using LoadModule module name  /path to. So file in httpd.conf and restart?